# Evaluate string as input keyword in matlab

Tags: matlab

How to evaluate a string which could be changed dynamically in code? for example:

```
A=rand(60, 60);
RangeC='10:end,:';
B=A(RangeC);
```

I know this is quite easy for others, but I have struggled for hours! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `eval` function but I would suggest to seperate RangeC in two variables like the example below. Also `end` won't be able to be evaluated so you can use `size` instead.

```
A=rand(60, 60);
RangeC1='10:size(A,1)';
RangeC2='1:size(A,2)';
B=A(eval(RangeC1), eval(RangeC2));
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!